# Need to return SqlDataReader with asynchronous database request

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asynchronous

The following method executes a query in a SQL Server database:

```
private bool authenticated(SqlConnection conn)
{
    string query = "some sql query";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    // the intent is to change this to: SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
       return false;
    }

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // do some stuff
       /*
        if (some condition)
            return true;
       */
    }
}
```

The method call to execute the query needs to be changed to an asynchronous version. However, the method would need to be changed to an `async`. Such methods cannot return anything other than `void` or `Task`. Writing another method just for the query execution has been considered, but `aysnc` methods cannot take `ref` parameters. What is the best way out of this?

Comment: As a side note, the `SqlConnection` class is not thread-safe. Be careful not to reuse it while an asynchronous request is pending. Also make sure that the `SqlConnection` instance is disposed when it's no longer needed. Otherwise you may end up with a connection leakage, and a starved [connection pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task<T>` can return what you need.

```
private async Task<bool> authenticated(SqlConnection conn)
{
    string query = "some sql query";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    // the intent is to change this to: SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
       return false;
    }

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // do some stuff
        if (some condition)
            return true;
    }
}
```